# Why even simple pages like phpinfo is cut off on specific server?

Tags: apache, output-buffering, php

On one of my clients production servers (Linux, Apache, PHP5) simple page output is returned partially and only to Google Chrome.

For example, I have set up simple phpinfo page, like `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

When I call that page like `http://192.168.1.1/phpinfo.php` on IE or FireFox it nicely returns whole phpinfo page.
But when I open this page in newest Google Chrome (v.30) it gets cut off at some point. Sometimes it's after 1-2 "screens", when I hit F5, it reloads longer chunk - 5-6 "screens" long, but still not all. If I hit F5 again, it returns 2-3 "screens" long page and so on.

Any ideas what's the problem here? Opening, closing Google Chrome don't help. Cleaning temporary files don't help. I have no more ideas :(

**EDIT:** Added screenshots to demonstrate this issue more clearly.

1) Opening phpinfo page in Google Chrome:
[image: first image]
you can instantly see that page is much to short for phpinfo

2) scrolling to the bottom and you can see that it's only part of phpinfo page
[image: second image]

3) now pressing F5 to reload page
4) as you can see - page is much longer now
[image]

5) but still not full php info page
[image]

6) Also I see error in Google Chromes console like this
[image]

7) and here is all request headers (sent / received)
[image]

**EDIT 2:** 
In FireFox page **almost** always loads as full page, but not always. Sometimes it also gets cut off. Only difference with Google Chrome is that in FireFox page always loads for at least 90%. In Chrome I sometimes even get page with only 5% of content in it.

Comment: screenshot would be nice.

Comment: @romaninsh a lot of screenshots added and also steps to reproduce

Comment: Please also see my edit nr.2. Firefox have same behaviour, but it's more "stable" :)

Comment: when you say it still only loads 90% in firefox, I think its pretty clear that your problem here isn't with Chrome loading less than 90%, but that no matter what browser you're using you don't get 100%.........

Comment: @Rooster Updated question title and tags

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: What does the log say? Can you turn up logging in apache, and tail the log for segfaults or other issues?
- What happens with a long static html page (avoiding the PHP engine). php -i > ./test.txt, then grab that page with the browser.
- If you view source is the entire page returned (maybe a custom style sheet is causign issues, or a proxy), or is it being truncated as well.